# p5js conflicting 2D and 3D rendering

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm a beginner to p5js and code in general. I'm working on a (hopefully) interactive website for one of my classes that uses two separate sketches that are controlled by the DOM. I think that the 3D and 2D rendering modes are fighting each other. Both of the sketches work perfectly separate from one another. I get this error message in Chrome developer "p5.js:16124 Uncaught not supported in p2d. Please use webgl mode". Here is my code:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="libraries/p5.dom.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch2.js"></script>
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="text" style="background: none; position: absolute; color: white; font-family: avenir,sans-serif; width: 250px; margin-left: 140px; margin-top: 50px; line-height: 15pt; font-size: 9pt; z-index:1;">
<p>
text
</p>
</div>

<div id="myContainer" style="background:none; position:absolute; z-index:-1; width:100%;height:100%;"></div>

<div id="myContainer2" style="background:none; position:absolute; z-index:-2; width:100%;height:100%;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Sketch 1

```
function setup(){
  var myCanvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight,WEBGL);
  myCanvas.parent('myContainer2');
}

function draw(){
  background(0,0,0);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);

  for(var j = 0; j < 50; j++){
    push();
    for(var i = 0; i < 80; i++){
      translate(sin(frameCount * 0.02 + j) * 150, sin(frameCount * 0.1 + j) * 110, i * 0.9);
      rotateZ(frameCount * 0.04);
      push();
      sphere(10, 15, 5); 
      pop();
    }
    pop();
  }
}
```

Sketch 2

```
var input, button;

function setup() {

  // create canvas
  var myCanvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  myCanvas.parent('myContainer');
  background(255,255,255,0);

  input = createInput();
  input.position(140, 675);

  button = createButton('Share');
  button.position(280, 676);
  button.mousePressed(greet);

  textAlign(CENTER)
  textSize(15);
}

function greet() {
  var name = input.value();

  for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {
    push();
    fill(255,255,0);
    translate(random(width), random(height));
    text(name, 0, 0);
    pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This operation doesn't work with 2d ([GitHub](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/core/transform.js#L137)). If you want to reverse x-coordinate and create object mirroring, just set translate and use -x for all x coordinates.

```
line(this.mirroring*0.5*grid_step, 0, this.mirroring*0.5*grid_step, 0.5*grid_step);
line(this.mirroring*2.5*grid_step, 0, this.mirroring*2.5*grid_step, 0.5*grid_step);
line(this.mirroring*0.5*grid_step, 0.25*grid_step, this.mirroring*2.5*grid_step, 0.25*grid_step);
```

Where this.mirroring can be -1 or 1. When this.mirroring = -1; reverse is toggled